# Pipelight [Silverlight] installation on Ubuntu

Tags: silverlight, ubuntu, installation

I'm newbie on Ubuntu and just wanted to install Pipelight. I typed following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mqchael/pipelight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
```

.... and Pipelight package cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

The Pipelight Package is available for Trusty (14.04), Saucy (13.10), Raring (13.04), Quantal (12.10) and Precise (12.04). You can find out your Ubuntu version with the following command:

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION
```

If you are not using one of the Ubuntu versions above, you will need to manually compile Pipelight.

To compile Pipelight you need to install wine-compholio with

```
sudo apt-get install wine-compholio
```

and then follow the instructions at http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html#section_1_8. This method has the disadvantage that you will need to repeat this step on every update and that you will not receive automatic security updates for plugins.

Since every version of Ubuntu, which is still supported for Desktop systems, is also supported by Pipelight I would suggest you to upgrade to a more recent version of Ubuntu. This will allow you to use the packages in the Pipelight repository and also ensures that you will receive security updates for the rest of your Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are just using the wrong package?

I think it's like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update

sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight5.0
```